Fail to create Python Interpereter - Poetry - Pycharm
Can't create new python interpereter with poetry. Although command points to a new installation of Python C:\Users\pruszyns\.local\bin\poetry.exe env use C:\Python311\python.exe Pycharm is looking for not existing python.exe
I tried to disable current environment basing on not exitsing python.exe


I'd try deleting that pypoetry/Cache directory and trying again.

To expand upon my comment...
By the looks of the error message, there are old virtualenvs in the Poetry cache that are referencing a base Python interpreter that's no longer available.
Since virtualenvs should always be recreatable, delete the pypoetry/Cache directory so Poetry will recreate the env with a still-installed interpreter.
